# Package for connecting R and Excel without the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xlconnect

A couple of months ago I found on the Internet information about an R package to connect R with Excel and the other way around (doing basically what `xlsx` and `XLConnect` do).

However, the main difference with respect to the two above mentioned solutions was that the package wasn't designed to use the JVM (which keeps giving me some trouble).

I've been spending quite some time trying to find the reference for that package, without success.

Can you help me?
Many thanks.

Comment: Hadley advertises https://github.com/hadley/readxl has no external dependencies. If it does (at some point), perhaps he can send you a hand written apology? :)

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: `readxl` package is only for _reading_ Excel files (and it looks like the OP needed writing as well).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to check out [openxlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html):

> openxlsx: Read, Write and Edit XLSX Files
>
> Simplifies the creation of
> .xlsx files by providing a high level interface to writing, styling
> and editing worksheets. Through the use of Rcpp, read/write times are
> comparable to the xlsx and XLConnect packages with the added benefit
> of removing the dependency on Java.